# Retrieve key-value from router post response?

Tags: node.js, express

When I search for a user using email, I get a response of the USER Schema but the thing is that I do not want the whole set of data, I just want a single field `balance`.

routes/users.js

```
//show balance
router.post('/balance',passport.authenticate('jwt', {session : false}) , (req, res, next) => {

  const email = req.body.email;
  User.find({email} , (err, users) => {

      if(err){
      return res.send({
          success: false,
          message: 'Error while retrieving the balance'
      });
  }

  return res.send({

    users

  });
});
});
```

Server response that I get

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "_id": "5d276ccccd1f520394e29bd7",
            "name": "george",
            "email": "fake@fake.com",
            "password": "$2a$10$w967rx9ZN50W0kQCE4X8IO/eGGS2YsXlbYgdjC7Sns380IbGbqvlS",
            "balance": 1000,
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, I only want this:

```
balance": 1000
```

Comment: simply do `return send({'balance': users.balance});`

Comment: thank you for the quick reply, i tried that before and i did again now, i get an empty responce ```{}```

Comment: actually, it looks like the response is inside an array, so it should be `{'balance' : users[0].balance}` (and recommended to do some checks the array is not empty)

Comment: Thank you so much it worked

Answer (score 0):

you can use `select` if your using `mongoose` model

```
User.find({}).select('Balance')
```

Comment: i get an empty reposne ```{}```

Answer (score 0):

You can use findOne, in order to get just one result instead of an array of results and also, you can use a projection to retrieve just the balance attribute:

```
// show balance
router.post('/balance',passport.authenticate('jwt', {session : false}) , (req, res, next) => {
  const { email } = req.body;
  User.findOne({ email }).select('balance').lean().exec((err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.send({
            success: false,
            message: 'Error while retrieving the balance'
        });
      }

    const { balance } = user;
    return res.send({
      balance,
    });
  });
});
```

Hope this helps